# Powershell get-content

Tags: powershell

I have a text file with multiple lines of numbers.  I am trying to use Get-Content to return the value on each line to it's own variable, to be used in an email.  However, instead of returning each number, it seems to be putting values on their own lines (for the most part), no matter how I write it.  What am I missing?

The input file has 3 values, each on it's own line.....88.6, 72.2, 0.01

The goal is to have the script assign $value1 = 88.6, $value2 = 72.2, and $value3 = 0.01

My PS code is below:

```
$data = (Get-Content C:\CumulusMX\summaries\daily_values.txt -TotalCount 1)[-1]
$data2 = (Get-Content C:\CumulusMX\summaries\daily_values.txt -TotalCount 2)[-1]
$data3 = (Get-Content C:\CumulusMX\summaries\daily_values.txt -TotalCount 3)[-1]

echo $data
echo $data2
echo $data3
```

However, it is returning:

.
7
2
.
2
0
.
0
1

With each character on it's own line.

Comment: This sounds like a [XY problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XY_problem) for me.  You could save the content of the file in a variable and access the content with the index. `$data[0]`, `$data[1]` and `$data[2]` for example. And why do you use `@data2` instead of `$data2`

Comment: @Olaf Typo.  Sorry!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It can be time consuming to read file multiple time.
More over, `-TotalCount 3` return the 3 first line of the file.

The problem comes from the **@** instead of **$**, echo is not useful in powershell.

Alternate solution can be :

```
$data,$data2,$data3 = (Get-Content D:\daily_values.txt -TotalCount 3)

$data
$data2
$data3
```